# How do I add event listeners to every element with the same class using jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I cannot understand why my code is not working. I am working on a popup modal when clicked. What is the right way to make it work? Thanks.

**HTML**

```
            <div class="projects-container">

                <a class="project">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img src="./images/background-project-filler.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class = 'project-title'>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </a>

                <a class="project">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img src="./images/background-project-filler.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class = 'project-title'>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </a>

                <a class="project">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img src="./images/background-project-filler.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class = 'project-title'>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </a>

                <a class="project">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img src="./images/background-project-filler.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <p class = 'project-title'>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </a>

            </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
        $('.project').each( (i) => {
            $('project')[i].click( () => {
                console.log(`Project ${i}`);
                
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed dot inside `each` function: change `project` to `.project`.

Comment: After fixing the typo the problem still consists